# Power BI - Update Connection Strings via API for AWS Redshift

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

**Here is what we are planning to achieve:**

- We have created reports using `AWS Redshift` as the data source. And,
  we can publish the `PBIX` files to the workspace using the Create
  Import API`(msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt243840.aspx`)
- We are trying to update the connection string on all datasets by
  using the Datasource API Set All Connections`(msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt748181.aspx`)

**I'm a Newbie to Power BI.. Seeking some guidance...**

- Let's say, we developed a certain report by pointing to AWS Redshift
     on Development environment. We are trying to automate publishing the
     developed report to say QA or Staging or Production environments;
     which means the published report will have to point to AWS Redshift 
     on QA or Staging or Production environments.
- Today, when we upload a `PBIX` file, the Power BI Service prompts us to
  provide ONLY the credentials. It doesn't allow us to change
     the    server information. And, what we want is the ability to
     change or    point to a different server. Any help here is greatly
     appreciated.
- This simply means, we'd have to create reports specific to each
  environment and this is not something we want.
- We were under the impression that Set All Connections API would
  come-in handy for us. But, we don't know how to produce a connection
     string that will help point the report to a different AWS Redshift
     database.
- So, we decided to take a crude approach, Create a report each against
  QA or Staging or Production AWS Redshift. Then query and
     retrieve the connection string for each reports' datasource. This
     gave us mashup connection strings' that look something like -
    `Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data`
     `Source=$EmbeddedMashup(blah-blah-blah-blah)$;Extended`
     `Properties="blah-bhaj-blah-blah-blah-blahblah-bhaj-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-bhaj-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-bhaj-blah-blah-blah-blah="`,
  but if you observe the connection string, you'll see `Extended

     Properties...` this is all encrypted information, not sure what
     information the encrypted string holds. And, in case we create
     different looking reports, the Extended Properties come out
     completely different which simply means we cannot have a standard
     mashup connection string. And, this crude approach won't fly.

So, what information we seek is how to point a report developed against a certain AWS Redshift environment point to a different AWS Redshift?

[Report Configuration Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/022FY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parameterize your connection information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-parameters. Use those parameters for server connections, and build the dataset again before publishing it.

you can then update those parameters by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup

Comment: Please explain your answer on StackOverflow, rather than just providing links. If the links you refer to disappear, your answer will no longer be helpful.